# Help in finding the fallacy in the following proof.

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

I'm currently studying Michael Spivak's *Calculus* and stumbled across a problem. I seemed to have proven a ridiculous statement:

Let $f$ be continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. Then given sufficiently small, nonzero $h$, we have $$\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$ for all $a$. This assertion is ridiculous, because it follows from this statement that $f(a+h) = f(a)$ for all $a$. However, I cannot find any error in the following proof:

Suppose $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$. Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$. Let $h \ne 0$ be such that $|h| < \delta$. Then, if $|x-(a+h)| < \delta -|h|$, we have $$a+h - (\delta - |h|) < x < a+h + \delta - |h|$$ $$\implies a+h - \delta + |h| < x < a+h + \delta - |h|.$$ $h + |h| \geq 0$ and $h-|h| \leq 0$, so the above chain of inequalities imply $$a - \delta < x < a+ \delta$$ $$\implies |x-a| < \delta$$ and thus  $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$, which implies $$\lim_{x\to a+h} f(x) = f(a).\blacksquare$$

What is the fallacy in the given proof?

Comment: Nothing guarantees that $|h|<\delta$ is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the following proposition:

> Let $f$ be continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. Then given sufficiently small, nonzero $h$, we have $$\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$ for all $a$.

What does that mean? The only way I can see to make sense of it is to say that it is possible to pick a value of $h$ such that $h > 0$ (though $h$ may be very small),
and then, using that same value of $h$ all the time,
show that $\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ for all $a.$

The flaw in the proof then is that it does not use the same value of $h$ all the time. For each new value of $a,$ for each possible $\epsilon > 0,$
it finds a $\delta > 0$ and then an $h$ such that $\lvert h\rvert < \delta.$
Each time you try a new $a,$ and each time you try a new $\epsilon$ for this $a,$
you may end up with a different $h.$ In fact, for must functions you *will* be forced to choose different values of $h$ depending on which value $\epsilon$ takes on.

---

If you change the limit to
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x)\right) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x),$$
where $f$ is any continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$
and $a$ is any real number,
however, you get a true proposition.

You might be able to argue that by taking the limit as $h \to 0,$
you always have a value of $h$ less than any value of $\delta$ you might need to use.
On the other hand, considering that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ (because $f$ is continuous) and $\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x) = f(a+h),$
I think the proof can be made easier.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I understand now. My only question now is: can this argument be applied to show that $\lim_{h\to 0} (\lim_{x \to a+h} f(x)) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ for all $a$, as long as $\lim_{x \to a}$ exists? This was the problem I was trying to solve before my misunderstanding.

Comment: That limit is true. The discussion is more than I wanted to try to fit in a comment, so I have appended it to the answer.

Comment: Oh! I meant, for non-continuous $f$. What if the only discontinuities of $f$ were removable discontinuities? Would that equality still hold?

Comment: As long as it’s continuous in a neighborhood of $a$ you can do it.